# Starting query from a defined first row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi StackoverFlow community,

I would like to do the following in Oracle SQL

Queried table looks like:

```
M_id  s_s_u             s_e_u              a_s_t  e_i   sr1  
K1    2020-02-19 13:00  2020-02-19 13:10   MS     P12   CI
K1    2020-02-19 13:10  2020-02-19 13:17   MS     P11   CI
K2    2020-02-19 13:04  2020-02-19 13:14   MT     P13   CD
K2    2020-02-19 13:14  2020-02-19 13:23   MT     P18   CI
```

What i would like to do is the following.

I load data every few hours. in a seperate table i record the last row per M_id.

so for the example above my table(where i insert the last row for each m_id per data load) will have the following records.

**Last records**

```
M_id    s_e_u                a_s_t  e_i   sr1  
K1      2020-02-19 13:17      MS     P12   CI
K2      2020-02-19 13:23      MS     P12   CI
```

I succesfully got the rows from MSSQL, but im struggling on how define the first row for the query to load from. There needs to continues flow of data thats why s_e_u of the last records = S_Su of the next record.

The current query for creating the first table in this post is quite long, i can share it if its  needed.

If you could push me to a solution direction on where i could use the records of the table last_records as a starting point for the actual query that would be great.

Comment: Is your example output meant to have the same row twice?

Comment: Nope. Just start from the previous value, without showing the same output twice

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the second table?

Comment: My bad. was a copy paste forgot to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Sound's like a gaps and islands problem. If you're looking for what I think, you should be able to do it with `match_recognize`; no need for the intermediate last records table.

Something like this:

```
WITH test_data AS (
    select 'K1' as M_id,to_date('02/19/2020 13:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_s_u,to_date('02/19/2020 13:10:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_e_u,'MS' as a_s_t,'P12' as e_i,'CI' as sr1 from dual union all
    select 'K1' as M_id,to_date('02/19/2020 13:10:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_s_u,to_date('02/19/2020 13:17:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_e_u,'MS' as a_s_t,'P11' as e_i,'CI' as sr1 from dual union all
    select 'K2' as M_id,to_date('02/19/2020 13:04:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_s_u,to_date('02/19/2020 13:14:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_e_u,'MT' as a_s_t,'P13' as e_i,'CD' as sr1 from dual union all
    select 'K2' as M_id,to_date('02/19/2020 13:14:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_s_u,to_date('02/19/2020 13:23:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as s_e_u,'MT' as a_s_t,'P18' as e_i,'CI' as sr1 from dual
)

SELECT m.m_id,
       m.match_overall_s_s_u,
       m.match_overall_s_e_u
FROM test_data c
match_recognize(
    PARTITION BY m_id
    ORDER BY s_s_u
    MEASURES
        FIRST(s_s_u) AS match_overall_s_s_u,
        LAST(s_e_u)  AS match_overall_s_e_u
    pattern ( 
        anything
        connected_val*
    ) define
        connected_val AS s_s_u = prev(s_e_u) /* Record is connected with the previous if its start equals the previous record's end */
) m
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want something like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.s_s_u > (select max(t2.s_s_u) from table2 t2 where t2.m_id = t.m_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. But i still experience the same where the new s_s_u for tbl2 is not the s_s_u of t2